# properties of protocol in extension cannot be used but why

Tags: swift, protocols

Just like

```
protocol  someProtocol {
  var p1:string
}

 extension someProtocol {
  func configP1(value:string){
   self.p1 = value  //error 
  }
}
```

In the extension of protocol, how to use the property which define in protocol

i know it  mutating func configP1(value:string){}    use mutating before the func that's ok

Comment: swift cannot support ?

Comment: are you sure even the first two lines of your "code" compile?

Comment: i know it   use the mutating before  the func configP1  that's ok

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

Basically every line of your "code" does not compile.

- `string` does not exist
- `p1` is missing get/set-specifiers
- the function is nor marked `mutating`

The correct code would look something like

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    var p1 : String { get set }
}

extension SomeProtocol {
    mutating func configP1(value:String){
        self.p1 = value
    }
}
```